# Create a model object when creating a user in Django, UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

And I am also using this function to create a family object when a user is created:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def user_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Family.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I have a couple questions:

1. I am getting an `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: family_tree_family.name` error, how to resolve it?
2. How to use the `**kwargs` in `user_created` function. I create users using `curl`.

Comment: Did you change `unique=True` to `unique=False` on the name field by any chance? If you have did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`? This kind of feels like your database doesn't quite match your model.

Comment: @Jacinator yes, I explicitly added `unique=False` to the name field, ran the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands. Still getting this error, when creating a user object.

Comment: That's odd. I would expect the model as written to have no constraint on that column.

Comment: Have you tried adding `blank=True` and `null=True` to the name attibute of the family model? I think you get the error message because you don't provide a name in the create method.

Comment: @JanikSpies I added these two attributes and reran the migrations. Oddly, it says no changes detected, and the error is still coming.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks to everyone who helped out.

I managed to figure the problem, and it was that the field `name` in `family` model must also be unique. Even if `unique=False` attribute was used. Therefore, the answer is to automatically create a unique `name` that does not exist before. Hence, I used `instance.username` since this value must always be unique:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def user_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Family.objects.create(user=instance, name=instance.username)
```

I would like to have a better alternative other than `instance.username`. Maybe if I could use `**kwargs` somehow.

Comment: Nice one man! Congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

In user_created try adding instance.family.save() after Family.objects.create(user=instance)

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def user_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Family.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.family.save()
```

and try changing user field in family class if that does not work.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried to create a Family object directly, this object takes `user` and `name` as attributes.

Comment: It seems like I figured it out. The field `name` must always also be unique, even though if I give it the `unique=False` attribute. Probably,  that's the doing of the `OneToOneField` in combination with the `user` model as the related one. Because `user` must be unique also.